# does web framework requires unique hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, yii, web-hosting

a very simple or stupid question may be...but i would like to know that these web framewrok require unique host or any php host can be used to get my site hosted.

what i mean is that there are certain host that are wordpress hosting and blah blah...so if i use framework like codeigniter, yii, zend....do they also require such host or any web host can be used which provide php hosting. previously i have developed two sites both are non framework based static site so i simply uploaded them on web host and enjoyed my work but now i m using codeigniter for my new site (my first framework ) . so this time do i need other host or any php host can provide it ....

Comment: You need a hoster, which supports execution of PHP scripts (maybe MySQL too). Most frameworks have no additional requirements.

Comment: If you're able to upload a basic website, you'll be able to upload a framework too, (It's just the exactly same as a basic website, just  *lots* more files.. ). Although, with the exception of some frameworks may need more PHP module dependencies.

Comment: If the framework is an architecture that you deploy to your web root, most hosts should work fine. If you need to install things to the server, you would need a server that allows for remote access to do that. That said, some hosts provide hosting for specific frameworks like Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

No, there is no link between a web hosting and a framework except the obvious for example the web host should support php for codeigniter to run.

## Long answer

Frameworks are nothing special. It is just pre-written php code which you can use. Example `codeIgniter` is just some php code. And so is web apps like wordpress. They all are nothing but just some php code. So all your web hosting service requires is to support recent versions of php
Any advertisement done by webhosting services about how they support wordpress and stuff are just marketing gimmicks. Any of the top rated webhosting service can prety much support any of the top rated php frameworks and web-apps

If you still want to be sure that if your webhosting service can run a particular php script, you can look up the requirements. 
**Here are the requirements for:**

1. [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/requirements.html)
2. [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)
3. [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation#requirements)
4. [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html)
5. [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html)

As you can see here, most of them if not all of them, require you to have **php 5** and some sort of database. **Typicaly MySQL**. These two requirements are pretty standard with most php web-hosting services

Comment: thank you vry much buddy...but just clear one more confusion...if any host can provide framework hosting then why these host says wordpress hosting available ...????...i mean those who are providing php hosting can also host wordpress...is'nt it..???

Comment: @roanjain `those who are providing php hosting can also host wordpress` you are correct. As I said, they are just marketing strategies. It doesn't mean anything at all. Any decent php webhosting can support any php script

Answer (score 4):

PHP frameworks are written in PHP themselves, and can be ran on any PHP host.

Things to watch out for are frameworks that require specific versions of PHP.  Most frameworks these days simply require PHP 5.3 or greater, which most hosts provide.

Also, there are some for-pay PHP applications that encrypt their source code with tools like ionCube.  These would require special hosting, but are rare.

Comment: This answer is somewhat incorrect. Not all PHP frameworks can be ran[sic] on any host as some require higher PHP versions than hosts offer (as is alluded to). For example, Yii2 requires PHP 5.4, yet GoDaddy runs PHP 5.3, and Dreamhost runs PHP 5.2.  Encoded applications are very common, but these do not require "special hosting", with most hosts either having support as standard or allowing support to be easily added, again e.g. GoDaddy.

Comment: @Nick I don't see how anything you say in your comment disagrees with anything in my answer...